# Multiple styles in one layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, symbology

I have a polygon layer and want to change the colour of single polygons.

Usually I use a rule based symbolization and filter the polygons be their "ID". But by that I have 30 or more rules.

Is there any other way to change the colour of single polygons in the same layer? For example with **select features by area or single click** ?

Comment: do you have a specific scheme or would just a random color per polygon work?

Comment: I have specfic colours for every polygon

Comment: You can store the color in a field and use that field for generate the color of a simple fill (small dropdown at the end-right of the color button). Select polygons, update the color field of the selected, invert the selection, update to other color. It's possible to link a small PyQGIS code for manage that at each selection.

Comment: You could use categories to assign colors randomly or by a color ramp, and then looking at the result change individual colors.  Once you have something you like you could save it as style or layer file

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a simple workaround with no Rule-based Symbolization.

Let's assume there is a polygon layer `"Layer_A"` (purple) with its corresponding attribute table accordingly, see image below.

[image: input]

Proceed with `Properties... > Symbology > Single symbol > Fill colour > Edit...`

[image: single_symbol]

Search for colours you want to use and connect them with polygons by `"id"` or any other attribute.

[image: condition]

*Schema 1.* When each feature is unique

```sql
CASE
WHEN "id" = 1 THEN '#colour1'
WHEN "id" = 2 THEN '#colour2'
...
ELSE '#colourN'
END
```

*Schema 2.* When the features can be filled with the same colour

```sql
CASE
WHEN "id" IN (0,1,2,3,4) THEN '#colour1'
WHEN "id" IN (5,6,7,8,9) THEN '#colour2'
...
ELSE '#colourN'
END
```

The output will look as following

[image: result1]

The same approach can be applied to `Fill style`, `Stroke width`, `Stroke style` etc.

---

Moreover, it is possible to get colours randomly using the following expression:

```py
color_rgb(rand(0, 255), rand(0, 255), rand(0, 255))
```

---

Additionally, you may try using a Python function.

In `'Function Editor'` create a new function with such code:

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface
import random

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def colfunc(feature, parent):

    layer = iface.activeLayer()

    for i in range(layer.featureCount()):
        c = lambda: random.randint(0,255)
        return '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(c(),c(),c())
```

[image: Function Editor]

Apply `'Save and Load functions'` and call this function in 'Expression window' with `colfunc()` and click `'Ok'`.

[image: Function]

So, the expected result might be looking as

[image: result2]

---

**References:**

- [Color Hunt | Palettes Color | Palette 184098](https://colorhunt.co/palette/184098)

Comment: Is it possible to add alpha to the result?

Comment: For sure, to which approach would you like to add the alpha?