# Randomising colour for many of polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-plugins, symbology, color

Is there a way in QGIS to randomise the colour of all the polygons present in a single layer?

I'm currently using QGIS 3.20.3 and a lot of the plugins for this that I've found online are not compatible (including Topocolour).

Comment: You also can find some information here : https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/363811/99589

Answer (score 10):

To get random colors, but be sure that to neighboring polygons are always in different colors, use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Cartography / Topological coloring` ([see documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/cartography.html#topological-coloring)). Run the tool and on the output, set `Data driven override > Assistant` for the color and choose the field `color_id` as `source`.

[image]

Comment: Please correct the color for Crimea

Answer (score 8):

Right click the polygon layer in the layers panel and go to `properties -> symbology`. Choose the `categorized renderer` from the dropdown menu on the top. As value use `$id`. Choose `random colors` as `color ramp`. Then click `classify`.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get a fixed number of colors and want to control which ones these should be, use the "regular" Single Symbol layer rendering and set a date driven override for the color. In the assistant, as `Source` set the expression `rand(1,5)` to get 5 different colors. Select a color ramp (or create your own) from whicht QGIS picks the 5 colors.

Like this, the colors are updated every time you zoom or pan. If the colors should be fixed, creat a new attribute with Field calculator and the same expression as above. In the assistant, then select the name of this field as source. So the colors will be random, but will not change any more.

[image]

[image]